# Join with delimited file with an awk command

Tags: shell, awk

I have writen this piece of code

```
for fichier in $(find $DATA $ARCH -type f -mtime $histo)
do
    compteur_lignes=$(cat $fichier|wc -l)
    echo "Nombre de lignes : $compteur_lignes"
      quantieme_f=$(date -r $fichier +%j)
    echo "Quantieme fichier : $quantieme_f"
    nom_fichier=$(basename $fichier)
    echo $nom_fichier
    awk -vquant_f=$quantieme_f -vtype_f='' -vNB_LG=$compteur_lignes -vnom_fic=$nom_fichier '{ if ( $1 == 01 ) {type_f=substr($0,21,7);printf "\n - Type %s, Quantième du jour de réception %s, Nombre de lignes du fichier %s, Nom du fichier %s\n" , type_f, quant_f, NB_LG, nom_fic}}' ${fichier} >> ${MAIL_CORP}
done
```

And the output is something Like That  :

```
 - Type TYPEN1, Quantième du jour de réception 126, Nombre de lignes du fichier 6, Nom du fichier Test.txt
```

I need to make a join with an delimited file on the first column :

```
TYPEN1:TRANSCON1
TYPEN2:TRANSCON2
TYPEN3:TRANSCON3
TYPEN4:TRANSCON4
```

To finally have this output :

```
 - Type TYPEN1 (TRANSCON1), Quantième du jour de réception 126, Nombre de lignes du fichier 6, Nom du fichier Test.txt
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk can work for you:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if (split($0,t,":")) a[t[1]]=t[2]; next} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
     {f=$i; gsub(/,/, "", f); if (f in a) $i=f " (" a[f] "),"} print }' f1 f2
- Type TYPEN1 (TRANSCON1), Quantième du jour de réception 126, Nombre de lignes du fichier 6, Nom du fichier Test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the output of your loop is `a` and the file is `b`, this would

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR { split($0,a,","); next }
         { 
           s= a[1] " (" $2 ")"
           for(i=2; i<=length(a); ++i) s=s "," a[i]
           print s
         }' a b
```

This processes the two inputs one line at a time. The first block is executed on the first input (because `NR==FNR`) and the `next` skips to the next input. The second block sandwiches the part from the second input into the first input.

output:

```
 - Type TYPEN1 (TRANSCON1), Quantième du jour de réception 126, Nombre de lignes du fichier 6, Nom du fichier Test.txt
```

There is an assumption made here, that the lines from both inputs will be in the correct order (easy to fix using `sort`) and there won't be any lines missing. Let me know if that's a problem.

Comment: @L.Quastana No problem. Although if it works perfectly, I'm surprised that you've chosen to accept the other answer that provides no explanation whatsoever of what it does. To be honest, neither of these solutions are _perfect_; you would be better off modifying your original `awk` script so that it processed the two files at once.